# Get whole row data in angular datatable on click

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-datatables

I have a table with adding rows dynamically using ng-repeat

```html
<div class="row form-group">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <table id="example" datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="row-border hover table table-condensed table-hover" ng-init="profileDetails()">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          <th>WHEN</th>
          <th>HOW MUCH</th>
          <th>RELATED TO</th>
          <th>WHAT FOR</th>
          <th>FROM</th>
          <th>THIRD PARTY PAYEE</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!--ng-click="format1(data)"-->
        <tr ng-repeat="data in OpenPaymentList">
          <td class="details-control"></td>
          <td>{{data.Date_of_Payment | date : 'MMM dd, y' }}</td>
          <td>{{"$" + data.Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Name_of_Associated_Covered_Device_or_Medical_Supply1}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Nature_of_Payment_or_Transfer_of_Value}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Applicable_Manufacturer_or_Applicable_GPO_Making_Payment_Name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Third_Party_Payment_Recipient_Indicator}}</td>
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
</div>
```

on click of any row nested row appears .. but for this i need to get whole data of row clicked not only the columns which appear.. i need the whole object "data" used in ng-repeat

```js
$scope.dtInstance = {};
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
  ////.withOption('serverSide', true)
  //.withOption('hasBootstrap', true)
  //.withOption('processing', true)
  //.withDisplayLength(10)
  //.withPaginationType('full_numbers')            .withOption('stateSave', true)
  //.withOption('searchDelay', 350)
  //.withOption('width', '100%')
  //.withDataProp('data');
  .withOption('order', [
    [0, 'desc']
  ])
  .withOption('bFilter', false)
  .withOption('lengthChange', false)
  .withOption('rowCallback', rowCallback)
  .withOption('createdRow', createdRow);

function createdRow(row, data, dataIndex) {
  // Recompiling so we can bind Angular directive
  debugger;
  $compile(angular.element(row).contents())($scope);
}

function rowCallback(tabRow, data, dataIndex) {
  $(tabRow).unbind('click');
  $(tabRow).on('click', function() {
    console.log('click' + data);
    $(this).find('.a1-icon').toggleClass('fa-rotate-180');
    var tr = $(tabRow);
    var table = $scope.dtInstance.DataTable;
    var row = table.row(tr);

    if (row.child.isShown()) {
      // This row is already open - close it
      row.child.hide();
      tr.removeClass('shown');
    } else {
      // Open this row
      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
      tr.addClass('shown');
    }
  });
}

function format(d) {
  debugger;
  console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Full name:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.Date_of_Payment + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Extension number:</td>' +
    '<td>' + d.Date_of_Payment + '</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr>' +
    '<td>Extra info:</td>' +
    '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>' +
    '</tr>' +
    '</table>';
}
```

controller code is as above.. as of now on click of a row i'm getting only data of the 7 columns which are there in table ...but i have like 25 data which are not displayed I would like to get all data of corresponding row so that i can use that info in nested row

Comment: Add a plunker or fiddle of working table

Comment: I i referred this plunk for my use http://plnkr.co/edit/gVf926obJKTXvXU7fLdA?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function inside your controller, pass to the function your current data, and return from the function a new object which contains all the other info you want to display. Then just display them.

Moreover, my suggestion is to avoid to append dynamically the HTML in this way. You can set up that row directly inside your HTML using tbodies. 
Just prepare your template there and use just an ng-show to show that additional info on click.

So actually you could do in your HTML:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="data in OpenPaymentList" ng-init="data.detailsVisible = false">
<tr ng-click="format1(data); data.detailsVisible = !data.detailsVisible;">
          <td class="details-control"></td>
          <td>{{data.Date_of_Payment | date : 'MMM dd, y' }}</td>
          <td>{{"$" + data.Total_Amount_of_Payment_USDollars}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Name_of_Associated_Covered_Device_or_Medical_Supply1}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Nature_of_Payment_or_Transfer_of_Value}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Applicable_Manufacturer_or_Applicable_GPO_Making_Payment_Name}}</td>
          <td>{{data.Third_Party_Payment_Recipient_Indicator}}</td>
        </tr>
    <tr ng-show="data.detailsVisible">
      // my new row and inside the cells I call a function of the controller which returns me the data I need
      <td>{{getData(data).myNewProperty}}</td>
      <td>{{getData(data).otherNewProperty}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

And inside the controller your getData function will return an object will all the new properties of the details:

```
$scope.getData = function (data) {
  // get all the values using the current data passed in
  return {
    myNewProperty: "hello",
    otherNewProperty: "world"
  };
}
```

I hope this helps.